# Loading entire CSS directory for all pages CakePHP

Tags: html, css, cakephp

just getting started with cakePHP, and the docs aren't answering my question.  I'm using a free admin template, Sufee template [SufeeAdminTemplate](https://github.com/puikinsh/sufee-admin-dashboard)

From what I read in the docs cake references webroot/css for all the styles so I copied all of the css files from the Sufee directory and pasted them into /webroot/css.

Now I want to load all those files, which there are about 10, for every page.

Right now I'm only able to get the css to render if I include this line on every page I need css:

```
echo $this->Html->css('style');
```

`echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome.min');`

This is not very efficient and I feel there should be a way to include the entire css directory for every page in the project.

Comment: You can use array instead of single link like: echo $this->Html->css(['style', 'font-awesome.min']);

Comment: @Sehdev Even that seems unnecessary and not up to standard. That would mean I would have to go to 50+ files and echo out that array of 10+ CSS files.  There has to be some other way in CakePHP...?

Comment: Are you not loading your css in default layout ? If you load your css in default layout it will load in your all pages.

Comment: @AlimonKarim Hey so I moved all the lines: echo $this->Html->css('style'); to /Template/layout/default.ctp, but now non of the css is being rendered on /Template/Pages/home.ctp.. The CSS will only render if I move all those echo statements into home.ctp

Comment: What does the source code say, are the echoed as it should be inside the head? Can you click them, do you see the stylesheet then?

Comment: As (bad) alternative, you could write your own helper, which loops the CSS directory and adds all CSS files...

Answer (score 0):

> Even that seems unnecessary and not up to standard. That would mean I would have to go to 50+ files and echo out that array of 10+ CSS files. There has to be some other way in CakePHP...?

What you do and also what you want to do is not efficient either. ;) Use something like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or another of the many bundler tools to build a single or at least a few CSS and JS files and just include them. This should be part of the build or deployment process. Also there is AFAIK no standard, just best practice, and best practice is to bundle that stuff.

What you want to do is **not** *efficient*, it's just *convenient* for the lazy developer. :) But it will cause a ton of requests and make the page load longer. There are plenty of articles on Google about that topic. [Here is a random one](https://www.lifewire.com/minimize-http-requests-for-speed-3469521) I've picked.

If you want to go the dirty and inefficient road, then you can simply extend the HTML helper or write your own helper that does what you want: Scanning a folder and then calling the HTML helpers methods for the CSS and JS files. However, I would **not** recommend to do so.